# Calculating probabilities of infinite possibilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose I have an infinitely long (countable) list of sentences, of which I know exactly three are true. I select a sentence at random. Intuitively, it seems like the probability of the sentence being true is miniscule. However, we can't use the concept of a discrete uniform distribution here. I want to know if there are any other mathematical tools to make sense of this case.

The intuition is that the probability of selecting a true sentence from the infinite list should be lower than the probability of a selecting a true sentence from a list of 1,000,000 sentences, of which exactly three are true. In that case, the obvious answer is 3 in a million. Is this just one of those times where there is no mathematical way to make sense of our intuitions, or is there another mathematical tool available?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{3}{n} =$?

Comment: There is no way to select randomly from countably many items, each with equal probability. So you have to say **how** you “select a sentence at random.”

Answer (score 1):

If you have countably infinitely many choices, what does it mean to "select one at random?"  There is no discrete uniform distribution on the positive integers.  This is your problem.  In layman's terms, if you ask someone to select a random positive integer such that the probability of selecting any particular positive integer is the same as any other, this is impossible.

However, if you apply some well-defined discrete probability distribution to the way you select a positive integer (e.g., geometric distribution, logarithmic, Poisson, negative binomial, etc.), then the probability of obtaining one of the three true sentences will be strictly positive.